# Why my VUE array elements are not rendered,

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can get the elements sent from the backend.But the text can't display.I don't know why.
here is my html :

```
              <!-- <form action=""> -->
                <div class=" form-group">
                  <input v-model="wd" @keyup="keyup($event)"  type="text" class="form-control" />

                  <!-- <ul class="list-group"> -->
                   
                    <table>


                      <tr>
                        <th v-for="item in title"><div style="width:500px">{{item}}</div> </th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr v-for="item in arr" :key='item'>
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.sort}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.company}}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                 
                </div>
```

here is My Vue:

```
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          wd: '', 
          arr: [], 
          listIndex: -1, 
          title:['name','sort','company'],
        },
        methods: {
          
          keyup(event) {

            var url = "/search/search/"
            axios.get(url, {
              params: {
                q: this.wd,
              }
            }).then(res => {
              console.log(res);
              
              this.arr = res.data.list; 
              
            
             
            })
            
          }

        }
      })
      ;
```

I know the data was got.Because the number of the items in loop is exactly correct.When I console.log(res.data.list),I can view the data from the backend.But they can't display in my page.
I will be very appreciate it if you could help me.Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr4IL.png)

Comment: What is the value of `item`? Chances are, `item.name`, `item.sort`, `item.company` are returning `undefined`, so the rows get rendered but no inner text is inserted.

Comment: But there is no such error in my brower.I'm not sure if it's wrong.

Comment: Undefined doesn’t necessarily throw an error. Try logging the value of item to console. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your reference to `this.arr` in your callback. When the AJAX call returns, `this` is scoped to the response, not your Vue object.

You can overcome this by inserting a variable prior to the AJAX call, like this:

```
var vm = this;
axios.get(url, {
```

then, in the callback, instead of `this.arr = res.data.list;`, do this:

```
vm.arr = res.data.list;
```

Comment: `methods: {
          keyup(event) {
            var am = this;
            var url = "/search/search/"
            axios.get(url, {
              params: {
                q: am.wd,
              }
            }).then(res => {
              am.arr = res.data.list;
            ` is this so?I did it.And it doesn't work.

Comment: This is incorrect. OP is already using arrow functions so lexical this is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The field `data` must be reactive

```js
data() {
  return{
   wd: '', 
   arr: [], 
   listIndex: -1, 
   title:['name','sort','company'],
 }
}
```

Comment: For the top level Vue app instance, the data does not have to be a function that returns an object: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data